# Cannot upload app to Chrome Web Store - "This item is not an app, please remove app section from manifest."

Tags: google-chrome-extension, upload, google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

I am constantly getting this error when uploading my app:

> An error occurred: Failed to process your item.
>   This item is not an app, please remove app section from manifest.

This is the manifest file for my Chrome app (based on the [Getting started - Hello World](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/first_app.html) tutorial):

```
{
  "name":"App name",
  "description":"app description",
  "version":"1.0.4",
  "manifest_version":2,
  "app":{
  "background":{
    "scripts":["background.js"]
  }
  },
  "icons":{
  "16":"icon_16.png",
  "18":"icon_128.png"
  }
}
```

I tried to install my application locally through the Chrome extensions section and it works just fine. I can see it installed in the Apps section of Chrome.

However, when I try to publish the app by uploading the zip file to the Chrome Web Store, I see the previously mentioned error.

Comment: I can upload this content without any problem. The problem is either in your `main.html` or in the way you create the ZIP. What exactly are you trying to upload ?

Comment: I create zip with above three files plus game.swf and two png icons, 16x16 and 128x128 pixels

Comment: I even simplified main.html to this <html>
<body>
Hello Woeld
<body> 
</html>the problem remains . I even tried to change encoding ANSI/UTF-8 and retyped the files by hand, still the same

Comment: That's strange. I can upload it without any problem. If possible post the source code somewhere so someone can take a look...

Comment: Wait I will try to add new item instead of uploading new version on the same one

Comment: Yes it worked. I uploaded all on a new item in my developer dashboard. Very strange :)

Comment: Most probably you were trying to upload an updated version of an item that was not originally recognised as a Chrome App.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<sub>[For anyone landing on this page while facing the same error message]:</sub>

The error mentioned above is a possible indication that you are trying to upload your Chrome App as an updated version of an already uploaded item that is **not** a Chrome App.

Comment: Did you verify this hypothesis, by uploading an extension then changing the extension to an app?

Comment: From your answer, it was not clear whether you were proposing a likely solution (=untested), or a probable solution (=verified). Your confirmation makes the answer more valuable.

Comment: I wrote the solution after the problem had been resolved (and I had verified it myself). The expression "possible indication" refers to the fact that I don't know if there are other situations (besides the one described in my answer) that produce the same error.

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issue while creating an Google apps marketplace app. Following config works. Interestingly if you remove `GOOGLE_DRIVE` as one of the items from the `container` node. I get "This item is not an app" error. I also get the error when I add an `app` node (applicable only to Google apps marketplace app)

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "name of the app",
  "short_name" : "short name",
  "version": "2.0.0.6",
  "api_console_project_id" : "your project id as string",
  "description" : "description",
  "container": ["DOMAIN_INSTALLABLE", "GOOGLE_DRIVE"],
  "icons" : {
    "96" : "icons/icon96x96.png",
    "16": "icons/icon16x16.png"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible for the following situation:
You are developing spreadsheet or google-doc extensions, while you are trying to update your app with manifest file, which can only be used for chrome app. Once you uploaded manifest file and tried to publish you script, you will receive the alert.
The solution is to click "discard changes" in the left bottom of publish page, which keeps the file as script app.