# Keep getting app error for google script add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-marketplace, google-apps-script-addon

I am trying to upload my google script to the marketplace, but when I try I get this error...

"This item is not an app, please remove app section from manifest."

My manifest in the google script is as follows...

```
{
"timeZone": "America/New_York",
"dependencies": {
},
"exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
"executionApi": {
  "access": "MYSELF"
  }
}
```

Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Possible reason could be the following. [You are trying to upload your Chrome App as an updated version of an already uploaded item that is not a Chrome App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20093353/cannot-upload-app-to-chrome-web-store-this-item-is-not-an-app-please-remove/45250999). Also, errors have been discussed on Google groups. Reference: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-apps/x6zszOpIIGQ and https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-apps/yJUzcbGs2-E

Comment: I eventually opened the script in a new sheet and launched from there (instead of a standalone google script file) and that worked.  So weird!